# Remove values above/below standard deviation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have a database that is made out of 18 columns and 15 million rows, in each column there are outliers and I wanted to remove values above and below 2 standard deviations. My code doesn't seem to edit anything in the database though.

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as r
import numpy as np


 df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\3-Last\\LastCombineHalf.csv')
df[df.apply(lambda x :(x-x.mean()).abs()<(2*x.std()) ).all(1)]
df.to_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\3-Last\\Removal.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you didn't assign the results back to `df`?

From:

```py
df[df.apply(lambda x :(x-x.mean()).abs()<(2*x.std()) ).all(1)]
```

To:

```py
df = df[df.apply(lambda x :(x-x.mean()).abs()<(2*x.std()) ).all(1)]
```